# How to fix 'Android is starting' optimization on every boot?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I recently updated to Lollipop on a Moto G (1st Gen).

It was running a bit slow, so I wiped by cache then performed a factory reset as recommended.

I now receive the '*Android is starting optimising app xx of xx*' every time I boot.

Obviously not life and death, but it's annoying to have to wait 10 minutes for every reboot.

**Is this a known issue and is there any way to fix this?**

Comment: This is common when using Xposed Framework beta for 5.x.  Do you have this installed?  Was the cache and wipe preformed within Settings, from stock recovery, or a custom recovery?

Comment: Run `adb logcat > log.txt` while booting and look for a line containing `dex2oat`.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same exact issue on the same exact phone. After doing some digging it seems like this happens when Android has a problem optimizing one or more apps, so it stubbornly retries all of them. So I uninstalled apps one-by-one and rebooted, and the problem went away after uninstalling SuperSU.

Not wanting to leave my phone unrooted, I noticed I had installed the latest SuperSU (2.79 SR3), so I went here and downloaded the latest stable release (2.79):

https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu

After installing it I no longer had any issues.

During my troubleshooting I also cleared the cache, although I'm not sure if it helped or not:

1. Boot to recovery
   For the Moto G 1st generation:

   1. Power off the phone
   2. Press and hold volume down button, press and hold power button, wait for about 4 seconds and then release both buttons
   3. Press volume down to select *Recovery* and press volume up to boot to recovery
2. Clear the cache
   For the Moto G 1st generation (stock recovery):

   1. If you get to a screen that says "No command"

      1. Press and hold the power button for 2-3 seconds
      2. Without releasing power button, press volume up button and release the volume up button
      3. Release the power button
   2. Use the volume buttons to move down to *wipe cache partition* and select it with the power button
   3. Wait for it to finish (it can take a while) then reboot

Answer (score 3):

For my 1st gen moto X , I was able to resolve the issue by:

1. clearing up disk space
2. updating all apps
3. boot through optimization (~130 apps)
4. clear cache (2.75MB remains)
5. power off (shut down)
6. boot through optimization (2 apps)
7. clear cache (3.5MB -> 2.84MB remains)
8. power off (shut down)
9. boot -- No Optimization!

I was at 500MB of free space and increased that to 5GB by deleting photos and downloads.

A few other ideas from around the net:

- Clear cache
- Clear up diskspace
- Boot into safemode [How to use Moto G safe mode (applies to Moto X and Moto E safe mode as well )? | Moto G Phone Guide](http://allaboutmotog.com/moto-g-how-to-guide/how-to-use-moto-g-safe-mode-applies-to-moto-x-and-moto-e-safe-mode-as-well/)

Answer (score 2):

It's because Android clears optimized `dex` files when it needs disk-space. Hence it's re-created during boot. You can read more in-depth debugging  details [here](http://giis.co.in/wasted_user_time.html).

If you have rooted device, you can try the following app; it locks the dex files, thus saving a lot of time:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.giis.optimisingappfixer